# Client service architecture

Tags: wpf, architecture, mvvm, service

I have a solution with following projects

- GUI (contains views)
- ViewModels (contains all view models)
- Service (a WCF service "TheService", which delivers remote data)

GUI knows ViewModels and service.
Service knows ViewModels.

The service has a method, which returns an `ObservableCollection` of `PersonViewModels`:

```
public ObservableCollection<ViewModels.PersonViewModel> LoadPersons() {...}
```

In the GUI, when I try to load persons I would like to do it as follows:

```
ObservableCollection<ViewModels.PersonViewModel> persons = service.LoadPersons();
```

The problem is my compiler says I have to cast

```
Service.TheService.ViewModels.PersonViewModel
```

to

```
ViewModels.PersonViewModel
```

Why this? I only would like to have one place where I define my view models.
It seems I have an architectual issue.

Comment: You have two similar classes that differs only with symbol "s" at the end.

Comment: Looks like you don't share the datatypes between your WCF contract definition and your Wcf Client

Comment: Sorry, I have only one PersonViewModel class. The 's' was a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I correctly understand your problem, but it seems that you have implemented classes representing the same thing in two separate places. The PersonViewModel class has been implemented both in the Service and in the ViewModels layers.

If the implementation from the ViewModels does not add any additional functionality, you should drop it and only use the implementation from the WCF Service.

If the implementation from the ViewModels does indeed add additional functionality which is needed in your application, then you need to create a conversion method from a Service.PersonViewModel to ViewModel.PersonViewModel, which you should use to make the cast from your example.

Comment: Thanks. My ViewModels are not implemented twice. They are all in the ViewModels Project. I think because its referenced both by the GUI and the Service Project I should cast. I will simply change the GUIs references from ViewModels.PersonViewModel to Service.TheService.ViewModels.PersonViewModel and everything should be fine.

Comment: Hi Michael, are you sure you haven't implemented twice? From the code that you posted it seems that the same class is implemented in two different namespaces (Service.TheService.ViewModels and ViewModels). Did you create the WCF client by hand from the ServiceContract interface or did you generate it (from WSDL if it is a SOAP service)? If you generated it, it might have generated the same class again.

Comment: Hi Florin, I implemented the service and the view model by hand. This is why I cant understand why my view model seems to be both in the ViewModels and the Service.TheService.ViewModels namespace. I thought maybe its because from the point of view of the GUI the services view model is another one than the ViewModels view model. I am confused. ;-)